# Importing React component from custom component library into HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, rollup

I created a test react component library (React, Typescript) and am trying to use Rollup to package it up into UMD to I can import the component into an HTML page.

The sample component I created just takes a `label` prop and colors it orange. Something super simple so complex logic would be taken out of the equation.

[image: Sample component in a working React application]

React code to render the above text:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Test from 'react-webpack-demo';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {
          React.createElement(Test.Brand, { label: 'Brand Label Text'})
        }
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The above component was packaged via Rollup into CJS format to be imported. I have also attempted to package the same content into UMD so it can be imported into HTML. The full `rollup.config.js` file is below:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

import packageJson from './package.json';

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: 'cjs',
                sourcemap: true
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: 'umd',
                name: 'Test',
                sourcemap: true
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-react',
                    '@babel/preset-typescript'
                ]
            }),
            external(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' })
        ],
        external: [
            ...Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies || {}),
            ...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies || {})
        ]
    }
]
```

I then attempt to import the newly packaged UMD file into my HTML page and render it into a DOM element as such:

```
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="./react-webpack-demo/dist/umd/index.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Testing rollup in plain HTML</h1>
    <hr />
    <div id='brand-test'></div>

    <script>
        const el = React.createElement;
        const domContainer = document.getElementById('brand-test');
        ReactDOM.render(el(
            Test.Brand,
            {
                label: 'Demo works!'
            }
        ), domContainer);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But I get the following error:

> The above error occurred in the  component:
>
> Brand@file:///Users/jacorbello/repos/temp/react-webpack-demo/dist/umd/index.js:33:1

> Uncaught TypeError: React__namespace.createElement is not a function
> Brand Brand.tsx:8
> React 17
>  test.html:20 Brand.tsx:8:11

Any help would be greatly appreciated here.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Did you try putting your script tag for library after react import script tags?

Comment: Oh.. my.. goodness, that absolutely worked! Thank you so much! I can't believe that's all that was.

Comment: Awesome! I've added it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the script tag is in incorrect order. Your library needs React to be imported before it's script can be executed.

Just fix the order to get it working

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="./react-webpack-demo/dist/umd/index.js" crossorigin></script>
```